# Rails Counting Child Models Conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumeration

So I have an app where a User has many posts. Those posts can either be published or drafted. I have this setup through an enumeration, it looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

The Post model:

```
class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  enum draft_status: [:draft, :published]
end
```

I'd like to set a controller variable that only returns Users who have any published pieces. How would I set such a variable?

I have tried:

`@bloggers = User.all.where('posts.published.any? =', true)`

That didn't work any idea how I would define this?

Comment: `@bloggers = User.where(id: Post.published.uniq.pluck(:user_id))`, or something like this.

Comment: You might consider a field for the `posts_count` on your `User` and keep track of the number if you look for this number very often.

Comment: Try this. `@bloggers = User.joins(:posts).where(posts: { published: true })`

Comment: @sergio That worked!!

Comment: @vishal I tried something similar to that and when i tried it exactly it gave me a PG Undefined column error.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Can you post the answer so that it could be easily referred later. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, for example:

```
@bloggers = User.where(id: Post.published.uniq.pluck(:user_id))
```

Comment: BTW `uniq` could be avoided here. ActiveRecord takes cares of it when we use an array in `where` clause.

Comment: @RohitJangid: it'll make the array generation much more efficient (will generate `SELECT DISTINCT` query).

Comment: If we avoid uniq its would be just simple sql query. If we use `uniq` then it would increase the runtime as it will fetch all the data from the database(sql operation), makes it uniq(ruby operation), and then fetch the user_id. So in my opinion, avoiding uniq would make it efficient.

Comment: @RohitJangid: I suggest that you actually run these queries in the console and observe resulting SQL. Did you completely miss my comment about `select distinct`?